# GoF builder and Liskov Substitution Principle

Tags: design-patterns, liskov-substitution-principle

In GoF there is a part about builder implementation issues. One of them says:

> Empty methods as default in Builder. In C++, the build methods are
>   intentionally not declared pure virtual member functions. They're
>   defined as empty methods instead, letting clients override only the
>   operations they're interested in.

Doesn't empty method violate LSP? It looks similar like inheriting `Ostrich` from `Bird` that can `fly`.

Answer (score 0):

LSP states that you cannot override a parent method without doing at least the same thing, plus extra behaviour that does not contradict the method purpose.

This is often achieved by calling the parent method first, then perform extra processing.

Since here, the parent method does nothing, overriding it does not violate the principle, (still provided you don't perform for example an operation like "substract" when the method name is called "add").

It must be guaranteed that the parent continues to do nothing in the future implementations. So to be sure, just call the parent empty method just in case...

Comment: Hence, the `Bird` could have an empty method called `fly` and `Straus` could be a bird?

Comment: ok but that would be a Bird not really flying since `fly` does nothing. An ostrich maybe?

Comment: @Narek You'd just have to make the intention clear. If you also have a `canFly` method then I'd say everything is fine. You may also segregate interfaces and have a seperate `FlyingBird` interface. That wouldn't let you treat all birds uniformely though.

Answer (score 0):

Your example (creating `Ostrich` from a `Bird` class which has a `fly()` method) is definitely an example of violating LSP.

But it is not fair to take that example in this case. If you clearly see as you say

> They're defined as **empty methods** instead, letting clients override
>   **only the operations they're interested in**.

So in this case if one is going to create an `Ostrich` class out of `Bird`  class which has an **empty** `fly()` method and `Ostrich` is not going to override it, then it won't do any harm, because though it is there it has no power.

But some people might say, though it is OK technically, conceptually it is not nice to have such. So actually it is not a problem with the pattern, but the implementation limitations we are facing with different languages.

Answer (score 0):

Ostrich cant fly but can run. So I suggest to rename `fly` method in the `Bird` interface with something like `action`. `Eagle` implementation will be 'flying' and `Ostrich` implementation will be 'running'.